# MySQL query to linq

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, linq, api

I have MySQL query

```
SELECT  Task_Number, BM_Number, BU, Status
FROM
    eng_effort 
    INNER JOIN eng_task on eng_effort.Eng_Task_ID = eng_task.Eng_Task_ID
where Status = "In Progress" and User_ID = "7"
group by Task_Number;
```

How do i write it in linq. please help.

Comment: What have you done so far? Do you already have done the connection to the db part or do you need help for this as well?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes : I have already done connection to be db using enity framework.. i want a that query to convert it in linq query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the LINQ syntax, you can write something like this:

```
var query = (from effort in context.eng_effort
            join task in context.eng_task on effort.Eng_Task_ID equals task.Eng_Task_ID
            where task.Status == "In Progress" && task.User_ID == "7"
            select new { task.Task_Number, ... })
            .GroupBy(a => a.Task_Number);
```

Also, are you sure `User_ID` is a text column?

With the extension method syntax:

```
context.eng_effort
    .Join(
        context.eng_task,
        effort => effort.Eng_Task_ID,
        task => task.Eng_Task_ID,
        (effort, task) => (effort, task)) // Using a ValueTuple here
    .Where(et => et.task.Status == "In Progress" && et.task.User_ID == "7")
    .Select(et => new { et.task.Task_Number, ... })
    .GroupBy(a => a.Task_Number);
```

Or you could perform a [Perform grouped join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-grouped-joins).

Comment: Thank you, yes User_ID is string.. from above query i need group by eng_task. Task_Number